# How to find the record with the maximum price?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, max, arel

This returns the maxium *value*, not the complete record:

```
self.prices.maximum(:price_field)
```

And currently, I find the record like this:

```
def maximum_price
  self.prices.find(:first, :conditions => "price = #{self.prices.maximum(:price_field)}" )
end
```

Is this the correct way ? Because the above needs two SQL statements to make it work, and it somehow does not feel right.

**Ps.** Additionally, I want that if more than one record has the same "maximum" value, then it should get the one with the latest `updated_at` value. So that would mean another SQL statement??

**Pps.** Does anyone know of a *good* or *detailed* reference for AREL and non-AREL things in Rails? The Rails Guide for ActiveRecord query is just not enough!

(I'm using Rails 3)

#### ===UPDATE===

Using AREL I do the following:

```
self.prices.order("updated_at DESC").maximum(:price_field)
```

But this only gives the maximum *value*, not the complete record :(
Also, is the use of `maximum()` really AREL?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
self.prices.order("price DESC").first
```

Comment: You could also use limit to reduce the database work load, number of objects instantiated, etc. by doing it this way: `self.prices.order("price DESC").limit(1)`

Comment: That's not necessary. Arel will add the limit automatically if you do '.first'